# Scraping Twitter Followers using Selenium

Tags: selenium, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I have links of few profiles and I want to get the usernames of their followers. I cannot use API as it is very slow and here I need thousands of the followers so I'm using selenium.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
time.sleep(2)

login_id = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r-30o5oe.r-1niwhzg.r-17gur6a.r-1yadl64.r-deolkf.r-homxoj.r-poiln3.r-7cikom.r-1ny4l3l.r-1inuy60.r-utggzx.r-vmopo1.r-1w50u8q.r-1lrr6ok.r-1dz5y72.r-fdjqy7.r-13qz1uu")[0]
login_id.send_keys("Username Here")


password = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("r-30o5oe.r-1niwhzg.r-17gur6a.r-1yadl64.r-deolkf.r-homxoj.r-poiln3.r-7cikom.r-1ny4l3l.r-1inuy60.r-utggzx.r-vmopo1.r-1w50u8q.r-1lrr6ok.r-1dz5y72.r-fdjqy7.r-13qz1uu")[1]
password.send_keys("Password Here")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("css-901oao.r-1awozwy.r-jwli3a.r-6koalj.r-18u37iz.r-16y2uox.r-1qd0xha.r-a023e6.r-vw2c0b.r-1777fci.r-eljoum.r-dnmrzs.r-bcqeeo.r-q4m81j.r-qvutc0").click()

driver.get("Profile Link")

time.sleep(2)


# Code to goto End of the Page
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(10)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

#get usernames element
usernames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
        "css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1ny4l3l.r-1j3t67a.r-1w50u8q.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg")
print(len(usernames))
for username in usernames:
    print(username.find_element_by_class_name("css-4rbku5.css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1loqt21.r-1wbh5a2.r-dnmrzs.r-1ny4l3l").get_attribute("href"))
```

I'm using above code to go to the bottom of the page and then extracting the username field.

[image]

Issue is that I'm only getting the usernames of 1st 20 r 30 followers.
Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your code just a little bit, you can try it out. Maybe you need to adjust the sleep timer again:

```
follower_list = []
# Code to goto End of the Page
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(1)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

    #get usernames element
    usernames = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(
            "css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1ny4l3l.r-1j3t67a.r-1w50u8q.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg")
    print(len(usernames))
    for username in usernames:
        username = username.find_element_by_class_name("css-4rbku5.css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1loqt21.r-1wbh5a2.r-dnmrzs.r-1ny4l3l").get_attribute("href")
        if username not in follower_list:
            follower_list.append(username)

print(len(follower_list))
print(follower_list)
```

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: Okay let me check